# Multiple clauses not working - NOT Starts with

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language

I am trying to write a query which sums the hours deployed to an action (Sorting), unless these hours are deployed to a certain type of action (i.e Holiday). This is for a labour tool I am creating.

For example, I have a list of 'Deployments' against people's names (i.e. Sorting 10).

I have a formula which splits this and sums the numeric values. However, I need to include an additional clause to exclude certain hours.

`=iferror(
ArrayFormula(
SUM(QUERY({'Ambient: Register2'!$A$11:$B,
TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX('Ambient: Register2'!BR$11:BR,,
MATCH(CP$1,'Ambient: Register2'!BR$1,0)),"[A-Z a-z]+")),VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX('Ambient: Register2'!BR$11:BR,,MATCH(CP$1,'Ambient: Register2'!BR$1,0)),"[0-9]+.[0-9]+"))},"select Col4 where Col1='M' and Col2='N' and (not Col4 starts with '#')",0))),0)`

This is my current query, and I have Deployed Sorting 1.5 and #Holiday 10.0 (hence the above formula is returning 11.5). I want to adjust the formula to only return 1.5 and recognize not to include the 10.0 hours of #Holiday, using the # as a character to signify to exclude.

Hopefully that makes sense?

I have tried `Col4<>'#%' , Col4 != '#%'` , `not Col4 like '#%'` etc.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Which column has the hours to be summed? `Query` will return col4 to be added but that column seems to have text in it ("#Holiday"?). Could you share a simplified non-private version of your sheet?

Comment: Questions that looks for help on non working "code" should include a [mcve]. In other words, simplify your formula to make it just include the QUERY function and include a sample data for input and output.